# How to display a dialog or actionshet withTiltle select and options camera, gallery and cancel on upload button click?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have no clue how can I display the below dialogue box on clicking the upload button.

```
var image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
var uploadBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.uploadBtn)
    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener {

       // how can I display dialogue or action sheet box on this click listener

    }
```

Comment: Use action sheet instead dialog

Comment: Use bottom sheet dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function use to show BottomSheet and create your custom layout and pass in inflate(Here)

```
private fun showBottomSheetDialog() {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_sheet_layout, null)
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
             dialog.setCancelable(true)
            dialog.setContentView(view)
            view.textViewcamer.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            view.textViewGallery.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            view.textViewCancel.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            dialog.show()
        }
```